# How to memory streaming in react native?

Tags: react-native

I am building a training app using react native. I want user just can open course files in the application and can use the app in offline and online mode. For this reason I encode files in a custom way in server-side. Now my question is how to decode file in the opening-playing time in application. File format is video, audio, pdf file.

Comment: This is a very broad question for this site - do you have any example code to post?

Comment: Assume I have encoded file in phone storage, for example video mp4 file how to decode it at runtime and playing it in the video player. just this part is my question.